# Would Celeron 1037U be enough to record 4 1080p video streams onto harddrive?

Tags: hard-drive, cpu-speed, surveillance, home-surveillance

Would Celeron 1037U be enough to record  4 1080p video streams onto harddrive?

I have personal NAS server which runs Ubuntu 14.04LTS.
CPU is Celeron 1037U.
Would that be enough to just pick up 4 video feeds from network surveillance cameras and dump on harddrive?

Im gonna be using motion software.

Comment: Perform a benchmark, consider the NAS isn't doing the actual recording, this is only a question of the bandwidth of your network.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Video surveillance minimum system requirements calculator](http://felenasoft.com/xeoma/en/help/calculator/) you need the following minimum system requirements for recording four 1080p video streams onto a hard drive.

- Processor: Core i3
- Memory: 1GB RAM
- Hard drive: approximately 22GB free space

Depending on what software you are using for recording the videos, it can get very angry if you don't give it enough hardware resources, especially if your recording software is a resource hog. If you are only dumping the four video feeds onto a hard drive without doing any recording, you could get away with using a Celeron 1037U processor.

From a software point of view, Ubuntu 14.04 is a compatible operating system for this task. Ubuntu Server has the additional advantage of requiring only low usage of your limited hardware resources.